# can not cancel pending orders

Tags: orders

We are using a magento extension for citrus payment methods.

In that extension,for pending orders, we are not able to cancel the order.

**indexcontroler.php**

```
<?php 

require 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';

class CitrusPay_Moto_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('moto/form_pay')->toHtml());
    }

    private static function _generateHmacKey($data, $apiKey=null){
        $hmackey = Zend_Crypt_Hmac::compute($apiKey, "sha1", $data);
        return $hmackey;
    }

    public function paymentAction()
    {
        $txnid = "";
        $txnrefno = "";
        $TxStatus = "";
        $txnmsg = "";
        $firstName = "";
        $lastName = "";
        $email = "";
        $street1 = "";
        $city = "";
        $state = "";
        $country = "";
        $pincode = "";
        $mobileNo = "";
        $signature = "";
        $reqsignature = "";
        $data = "";
        $flag = "dataValid";
        $respdata = "";

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
        $orderid=-1;

        $apiKey = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/moto/apikey');

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            $signatureFlag = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/moto/matchSignature');

            $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

            $txnid = $postdata['TxId'];
            $data .= $txnid;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Citrus Transaction Id: </strong>".$txnid;

            $orderid=$txnid;
            $order->loadByIncrementId($orderid);

            $TxStatus = $postdata['TxStatus'];
            $data .= $TxStatus;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Transaction Status: </strong>".$TxStatus;

            $amount = $postdata['amount'];
            $data .= $amount;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Amount: </strong>".$amount;

            $pgtxnno = $postdata['pgTxnNo'];
            $data .= $pgtxnno;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>PG Transaction Number: </strong>".$pgtxnno;

            $issuerrefno = $postdata['issuerRefNo'];
            $data .= $issuerrefno;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Issuer Reference Number: </strong>".$issuerrefno;

            $authidcode = $postdata['authIdCode'];
            $data .= $authidcode;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Auth ID Code: </strong>".$authidcode;

            $firstName = $postdata['firstName'];
            $data .= $firstName;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>First Name: </strong>".$firstName;

            $lastName = $postdata['lastName'];
            $data .= $lastName;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Last Name: </strong>".$lastName;

            $pgrespcode = $postdata['pgRespCode'];
            $data .= $pgrespcode;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>PG Response Code: </strong>".$pgrespcode;

            $pincode = $postdata['addressZip'];
            $data .= $pincode;
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>PinCode: </strong>".$pincode;

            $signature = $postdata['signature'];

            $respSignature = self::_generateHmacKey($data,$apiKey);

            /* Suppose a Custom parameter by name Roll Number Comes in Post Parameter.
             * then we need to retreive the RollNumber as
            * $rollNumber = $postdata['Roll Number'];
            * For other custom parameters as well this code can be used to retreive them. */

            if($signature != "" && strcmp($signature, $respSignature) != 0)
            {
                $flag = "dataTampered";
            }
            $txMsg = 'CitrusPay: '.$postdata['TxMsg'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Citrus Transaction Message: </strong>".$txMsg;
            $txnGateway = $_POST['TxGateway'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Transaction Gateway: </strong>".$txnGateway;
            /*$issuerCode = $_POST['issuerCode'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Issuer Code: </strong>".$issuerCode;
            $paymentMode = $_POST['paymentMode'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Payment Mode: </strong>".$paymentMode;
            $maskedCardNumber = $_POST['maskedCardNumber'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Card Number: </strong>".$maskedCardNumber;
            $cardType = $_POST['cardType'];
            $respdata .= "<br/><strong>Card Type: </strong>".$cardType;*/
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response received is ".$TxStatus);
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response Message is ".$txMsg);
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response signature recieved is ".$signature);
            //Mage::log("Citrus Response signature generated is ".$respSignature);
            if($TxStatus == 'SUCCESS')
            {
                if($signatureFlag == 'Y')
                {
                    if($flag != "dataValid")
                    {   
                        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);                      
                        $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Citrus Response signature does not match. You might have received tampered data")->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                        $order->cancel()->save();
                        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setErrorMessage("<strong>Error:</strong> Citrus Response signature does not match. You might have received tampered data");
                        Mage::log("Citrus Response signature did not match ");
                        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure');
                    }else{
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($txMsg);
                        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
                        $order->addStatusHistoryComment($txMsg)->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                        $order->save();                     
                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();    
                        Mage::log("Citrus Response Order success..");
                        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success');
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Mage::log("Citrus Response - Must enable signature validation in Admin...");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
                // Inventory updated 
                $this->updateInventory($orderid);
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($txMsg)->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->cancel()->save();               
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setErrorMessage("<strong>Error:</strong> $txMsg <br/>");
                Mage::log("Citrus Response Order canceled ..");
                $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure');
            }
        }
        Mage::log("Citrus Transaction END from Citruspay");
    }

    public function updateInventory($order_id)
    {

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
        {
           $ordered_quantity = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
           $sku=$item->getSku();
           $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
           $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId())->getQty();

           $updated_inventory=$qtyStock + $ordered_quantity;

           $stockData = $product->getStockItem();
           $stockData->setData('qty',$updated_inventory);
           $stockData->save(); 

       } 
    }


}
```

Comment: if your module is unable to do it by some reason, then you can achieve this by using observer

Comment: can you please help me how i can do it ?

Comment: this is the payment method code : "moto" can you please help me with observer code

Comment: After you get order success then you want to delete order if payment is pending ??

Comment: i want to cancel the order only if payment id failed

Comment: once we placed an order, automatically invoice option is generated in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
File: app/code/local/Letsknowit/Postdata/Checkout/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
       <models>
         <postdata>
            <class>Letsknowit_Postdata_Model</class>
          </postdata>
       </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
       <observers>
         <postDataTosServer>
            <type>singleton</type>
              <class>Letsknowit_Postdata_Model_Checkout_Observer</class>
              <method>postDataTosServer</method>
        </postDataTosServer>
      </observers>
     </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>   
  </global>   
  </config>
```

File: app/code/local/Letsknowit/Postdata/Model/Checkout/Observer.php

```
    <?php 
    class Letsknowit_Postdata_Model_Checkout_Observer 
        {
        public function postDataTosServer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
Mage::log(print_r($orderIds),null,'ordeid.log');
            foreach($orderIds as $_orderId){
            $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
            if($order->getStatus() =='pending'){
                $order->cancel();
                $order->save();
                }

            }

        }
    }   

    ?>
```

**Second method :** 
override Mage OnePageController and called my custom function. Below is the code to override onestep checkout.

app\etc\modules\Namespace_Module.xml

```
<Namespace_Checkout>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
</Namespace_Checkout>
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Checkout\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
  <modules>
     <Namespace_Checkout>            
        <version>0.1.0</version>        
     </Namespace_Checkout>    
  </modules>        
    <frontend>        
        <routers>            
            <checkout>                
                <args>                    
                    <modules>                        
                        <Namespace_Checkout before="Mage_OneStepCheckout">Namespace_Checkout</Namespace_Checkout>                    
                    </modules>                
                </args>            
            </checkout>        
        </routers>    
    </frontend>     
</config>
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class Namespace_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController{
    public function successAction(){
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
        $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
        if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $this->customFunction($lastOrderId); // Custom function to call

        $session->clear();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    function customFunction($_orderId){
        // This function is calling before clearing order session
        //Here you can put all your custom code 
            $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
            if($order->getStatus() =='pending'){
                $order->cancel();
                $order->save();
                }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i tried this, but still can not able to cancel

Comment: I have putted the debuging code in observer please se your log   ordeid.log file and post here

Comment: i didt saw "ordeid.log" file in var folder, is there any other place i need to check

Comment: it means  this module is not working,have you cleared the cache ?

Comment: yes, cache was disabled. but i can succesfully place an order and make payement. but cancelling non paid order is problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer with second option my first method also working on my end

Comment: are you trying for other payment method

Comment: It's based on event not on payment or shipping it will cancel order whose status is "pending"

Comment: okay, i am trying second method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35961/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-arunendra).